# TPC doesnt work in CodeFirst-Migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration, code-first

I have below class :

```
 public abstract class BaseAttachment
{
    public Guid BaseAttachmentId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public string FileSize { get; set; }
    public Folder Folder { get; set; }
    public Guid? FolderId { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

And I have below Table and Inherite `BaseAttachment` :

```
public class ProductGallery : BaseAttachment
{
    public ProductHeader ProductHeader { get; set; }
    public Guid? ProductHeaderId { get; set; }
}
```

and this :

```
 public class Attachment:BaseAttachment
{

}
```

when Run Project and Create Database I have Below Tables :

```
BaseAttachment,ProductCategory
```

instead Of One Table (`BaseAttachment`) . 
**why ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a config Class Like this for `ProductCategoryConfig` and Set TableName with below :

```
 public class ProductGalleryConfig:EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductGallery>
{
   public ProductGalleryConfig()
   {
       ToTable("ProductGallery");
       Property(row => row.Code).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
       Property(row => row.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
       HasRequired(row => row.ProductHeader).WithMany(row => row.Galleries).HasForeignKey(row => row.ProductHeaderId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
   }
}
```

and Comment below Line and its fix.

```
//    ToTable("ProductGallery");
```